# User creates his e-mail id on joomla site

Tags: joomla1.5, email

I'm new to joomla and I am looking for a module or component that allows users to create their e-mail id on my domain.

I've purchased the mail space from my provider but I don't know how to use it.

I want a full mailing feature in my website. Please guide me.

Comment: You need a component that will create mail account on your server for users that open an account on your Joomla site?

Comment: yup.. :-S

is there any available???

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on your web/email provider. Contact them first. I have never seen anyone offering an API for managing email accounts, so I'm not very hopeful.